# React Native onpress not working

Tags: react-native

`onRadioPressed` does not seem to be called - what am I doing wrong?  I also need to get the text contained in the 'clicked' item.

I believe I can get that with `event.nativeEvent.text`, correct?

Thanks for any help.

```
class RadioBtn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  onRadioPressed(event) {
    console.log('RADIOBUTTON PUSHED:');
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.radioGrp}>
            <View style={styles.radioContainer}>
                <TouchableHighlight onpress={() => this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
                    <Text style={styles.radio}>Left</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.radioContainer}>
                <TouchableHighlight onpress={() => this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
                    <Text style={styles.radio}>Right</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: onpress event should be trigger with `onPress={()=>{console.log('pressed')}` however onPress shouldn't work on flatList you should use ToucableOpcity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So here:

```
<TouchableHighlight onpress={() => this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
    <Text style={styles.radio}>Left</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

First change `onpress` to `onPress`. Here `() => this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)` you are specifying an arrow function that returns another function `this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)` but you never trigger it.

Correct ways:

```
// You can do either this
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onRadioPressed()} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
    <Text style={styles.radio}>Left</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

// Or you can do either this
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
    <Text style={styles.radio}>Left</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

I would recommend checking this article out https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.irpdw9lh0

Answer (score 2):

You can not bind the function inside onpress link this :

```
<TouchableHighlight onpress={() => this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
```

use it like this :

```
<TouchableHighlight onpress={() => this.onRadioPressed()} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
```

if you want to bind the function then try this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onpress={this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
```

Cheers:)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond but the first answer was all I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use below line

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onRadioPressed.bind(this)} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
```

or using arrow function

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onRadioPressed()} underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
```

Answer (score 2):

if https://stackoverflow.com/a/41651845/9264008 doesn't works check the way you have imported `TouchableOpacity`

✅ **correct** import `import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'`

sometimes mistakenly weird import happens example below

❌ Import `import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'`

Answer (score 0):

**I'm using react-native 0.66 version and it's working fine.**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Text,View } from "react-native";


    const App = () =>  {
    
      const [ prevCount, setCount ] = useState(1)
    
      const onPress = () => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.prevCount}> {prevCount} </Text>
            <Text style={styles.pressHere} onPress={onPress} > Press Here </Text>
        </View>
      )
    
    };
    
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        marginTop: 50
      },
      pressHere:{
        fontSize: 30
      },
      prevCount: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'red'
      }
    })
    
    export default App;
```

also, you can use [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text) doc.